# Rock Paper Scissors for Odin Project

Tags: javascript

I am having issues finishing a JavaScript rock paper scissors game for the Odin Project. Currently, I can get the game to run for 5 rounds but it does not keep score or log the player or computer selections to the console. Also, some undefined variables are popping up. I am unable to figure it out right now.

Here is my code:

```js
// Determines computer choice and randomizes selection
function getComputerChoice() {
  const options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  const randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
  return options[randomChoice];
}

//Runs the game
function game() {
  let roundsPlayed = 0;
  let playerScore = 0;
  let computerScore = 0;
  let rpsChamp = "";

  // loop game for 5 rounds. Track rounds and score
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    const playerSelection = prompt("Choose Your Weapon", "Rock, Paper, Scissors").toLowerCase();
    // console.log(playerSelection)
    // console.log(computerSelection)
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    console.log("Player Win Totals " + playerScore);
    console.log("Computer Win Totals " + computerScore);

    // Plays round to determine winner
    function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
      if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return `It's a Tie, You both picked ${playerSelection}`;
      } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        computerScore++
        return "The Computer Wins! Paper beats Rock";
      } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        computerScore++
        return "The Computer Wins! Scissors beats Paper";
      } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        computerScore++
        return "The Computer Wins! Rock beats Scissors";
      } else if (playerSelection === "Rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
        playerScore++
        return "Nice! You Win! Rock beats Scissors";
      } else if (playerSelection === "Paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
        playerScore++
        return "Nice! You Win! Paper beats Rock";
      } else if (playerSelection === "Scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
        playerScore++
        return "Nice! You Win! Scissors beats Paper";
      }
    }
  }
  // determine winner of 5 round game  
  if (playerScore > computerScore) {
    rpsChamp = "Winner! You beat the Computer!";
  } else if (playerScore === computerScore) {
    rpsChamp = "You tied with the Computer. Try Again!"
  } else {
    rpsChamp = "Loser! You lost to the Computer"
  }

  // Reports who won the game  
  console.log("After Five Rounds, The Winner is: " + rpsChamp);
}

// Starts the game
game();
```

Comment: You're converting the player's selection to lowercase, but not the computer's selection. So they'll never be equal, and the player's selection will never equal any of the strings you compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the player's choice is never going to be `"Rock"` `"Paper"` or `"Scissors"`; On line 18 when you prompt for input, you use `.toLowerCase()`.

This makes it so that if you type, for example, `"Rock"` it gets turned into `"rock"` and then when your code checks if `playerSelection === "Rock"` it will always return false.